# Drawbacks of single-field inflationary models with $\phi^2$ or $\phi^4$ potential?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

I am aware that existing models of inflation, especially the single field chaotic inflation with quadratic or quartic potential, e.g.
$$
V = \frac12 m^2 \phi^2 \qquad \text{or} \qquad \lambda \phi^4
$$
explain observations perfectly. See, e.g., the Planck data:

> [image]
>
> Taken from [Planck 2013 results. XXII. Constraints on inflation](http://inspirehep.net/record/1224747?ln=en)

Then why are we still trying for alternative models of inflation, e.g. models like Higgs inflation?

Comment: Hi Jose. It isn't clear what you are asking. Are you referring to some recent publication that claims we need a new model of inflation?

Comment: This is completely clear. @john there's lots of research about new models of scalar field inflation

Comment: Tip to editors: It is easy to overlook the title when one edits. Remember to spell-check the title.

Comment: "existing models of inflation ... explain observations perfectly" -- citation needed. Note too that inflation was born a purely retrodictive theory; the point was not to confirm predictions with observations, but to be more aesthetically pleasing in the eyes of its creators, and some people find other models of inflation more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: @Qmechanic oops, my bad.

Comment: Thankyou @innisfree for editing my question to a much better form. So all it have to do with is aesthetic beauty. I have a rough idea like the transpanckian values of scalar field, the extremey high values of the mass, the extremely small values of $\lambda$ etc are problems